# import glob text file from php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqlimport

My glob code finds the file and attempts to insert it into the table but fails.  I couldn't find anyone that is asking the same question.  I will have many files that need to be inserted into the same table.  It is a coma delimited text file.

**Updated code***

The following code works as long as I rem the load data line.  When I use the load data command manually, it works.  I have not found a post example that has solved the problem "Why does the load data command not work?"

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'schaadan_hash');
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo "Connected. ";
    echo "<br />";
}
$upload = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'ntlmhash2_1.txt' INTO TABLE ntlm2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'(`clear` , `hash`);";
mysqli_query($con,$upload);
?>
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging. At which point does it break? What output are you getting? What does `$files` contain? What errors does mysqli return to you (which you are not catching right now? What is the output of your `printf($file);`?

Comment: The output are the files that start with ntlmhash2.  The file contains mulitple lines that contain a character comma then the ntlm hash.

Comment: Please select your whole code and hit the `{}` button to indent it. Please remove the individual backticks around each line.

Comment: Also, there are no errors when I use "or die..."